# How to ensure unique users registration

Tags: grails, logic

I wonder what is the best way to ensure unique users. I will issue a common instruction to 100 people to my website. Once they come to my site, I'll need to allocate them to North south east west region, one after another. I also need to prevent one user from having many accounts. (The user may use another computer / their phone to access)

What is the best way to do this in grails?

Answer (score 2):

There no way to be 100% sure that all users are uniq, btw you if you gather and validate as much details as possible, like:

- email (you know), easy to counterfeit btw
- cell number (send text message with special code to confirm number), but user can also use a friend number, or buy new one
- ask for scan of person ID, and/or
- address verification (require scan of bill/other pappers with full user name and address on it, or send a letter to this address with special code to confirm)

Answer (score 1):

Are you controlling who gets the initial instructions, like from a contact list or something? If so could include a "registration key" and only let a particular key register once, or only let those particular email addresses be used to register (once), or even create the users ahead of time and send them the instructions to login.